# How to navigate with Navigator 2.0 without a State?

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation

I have a very simply scenario. A button where when pushed would transition to the next screen. In Navigator 1.0, it is very simple to do by:

```
ElevatedButton(
  onPressed: () {
    // Navigate to next screen.
    Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => NextScreen()),
    );
  },
  child: Text('Next Screen!'),
)
```

It seems that with `Navigator 2.0` I would need to have a state to keep track of the current screen.

```
...
Navigator(
    pages: [
        MainScreenPageRoute()

        if (state.isNextScreen) {
            NextScreenPageRoute()
        }
    ],
    onPopPage: (route, result) {
        // would have to keep track of this value
        state.isNextScreen = false; 
        return route.didPop(result); 
    },
)
...
```

As for before I don't have to keep track of a state just to navigate, In `Navigator 2.0` it seems that it is required. Is it really the case? If so do you guys have any suggestion of how to handle this properly?

P.S.
It also feels like now I have to keep track of the state which adds to more work compared to before.

Answer (score 0):

yes in navigator 2 you change the page when you change the state.

There are some packages that help you to avoid this like [qlevar_router](https://github.com/SchabanBo/qlevar_router)

see this example

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:qlevar_router/qlevar_router.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final books = [
    Book('Stranger in a Strange Land', 'Robert A. Heinlein'),
    Book('Foundation', 'Isaac Asimov'),
    Book('Fahrenheit 451', 'Ray Bradbury'),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => MaterialApp.router(
      routeInformationParser: QRouteInformationParser(),
      routerDelegate: QRouterDelegate([
        QRoute(path: '/', builder: () => BooksListScreen(books)),
        QRoute(
            path:
                '/books/:id([0-${books.length - 1}])', // The only available pages are the pages in the list
            builder: () => BookDetailsScreen(books[QR.params['id']!.asInt!])),
      ]));
}

class Book {
  final String title;
  final String author;

  Book(this.title, this.author);
}

class BooksListScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Book> books;
  BooksListScreen(this.books);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: ListView(
        children: [
          for (var book in books)
            ListTile(
                title: Text(book.title),
                subtitle: Text(book.author),
                onTap: () => QR.to('/books/${books.indexOf(book)}'))
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class BookDetailsScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final Book book;
  BookDetailsScreen(this.book);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Text(book.title, style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline6),
            Text(book.author, style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle1),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

don't forget to add `qlevar_router: 1.4.0` in `pubspec.yaml`

Comment: the thing is it makes sense when you already have a state to keep track of (selected book in your example), but for a simple push to next screen without passing in state, it feels like an overkill.